# Combine 2 SQL query (PostgreSQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql, web-analytics

I'm trying to find out the bounce rate of the top 10 UTM source. There is no column for bounces in the table so I have to query it. I've created a query to find the TOP 10 UTM source and another query to find bounce rate. I just can't seem to figure out how to combine both of this queries together.
The database table contains:

> 1) cuuid -cookie ID
>
> 2) session - session
>
> 3) duration
>
> 4) Each row represents a page view

```
SELECT
TOP 10 regexp_replace(regexp_substr(url, 'utm_source\\=[^\\&]*'), 'utm_source='),
COUNT(DISTINCT(cuuid)) as "Total Unique Visitors",
COUNT(DISTINCT(session)) as "Total Unique Sessions",
COUNT(*) as "Total Page Views",
CAST(COUNT(DISTINCT(session)) AS FLOAT)/CAST(COUNT(DISTINCT(cuuid)) AS FLOAT) AS "Average Sessions per Visitor",
CAST(COUNT(*) AS FLOAT)/CAST(COUNT(DISTINCT(session)) AS FLOAT) AS "Average Pageview per Session",
ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN duration < 0 THEN 0 ELSE duration END)::FLOAT/COUNT(DISTINCT(session))) AS "Average Duration per Session"
FROM table1
WHERE url ILIKE '%%utm_source%%'
AND ts>='2018-05-01'
AND ts < '2018-06-01'
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 2 DESC;


--add bounce rate query into first--

SELECT
CAST((CAST((SUM(bounces)*100) AS FLOAT)/CAST(COUNT(*) AS FLOAT)) AS VARCHAR(5)) + '%' as "Bounce rate"
FROM (
    SELECT
    MIN(ts) AS "time_first_viewed",
    cuuid,
    session,
    COUNT(*) as "number_of_events",
    CASE WHEN count(*) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS bounces
    FROM table1
    WHERE ts>='2018-05-01'
    AND ts < '2018-06-01'
    GROUP BY cuuid, session)
```

For the final result, I need it to be in the same table. And the columns are:

> 1)UTM Source
>
> 2)Unique Visitor
>
> 3)Unique Sessions
>
> 4)Page View
>
> 5)Session/Visitor
>
> 6)Pageview/session
>
> 7)Avg Duration
>
> 8)Bounce Rate

Answer (score 0):

you just do like the below with comma :
hope this works

```
Select * from 
(SELECT
TOP 10 regexp_replace(regexp_substr(url, 'utm_source\\=[^\\&]*'), 'utm_source='),
COUNT(DISTINCT(cuuid)) as "Total Unique Visitors",
COUNT(DISTINCT(session)) as "Total Unique Sessions",
COUNT(*) as "Total Page Views",
CAST(COUNT(DISTINCT(session)) AS FLOAT)/CAST(COUNT(DISTINCT(cuuid)) AS FLOAT) AS "Average Sessions per Visitor",
CAST(COUNT(*) AS FLOAT)/CAST(COUNT(DISTINCT(session)) AS FLOAT) AS "Average Pageview per Session",
ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN duration < 0 THEN 0 ELSE duration END)::FLOAT/COUNT(DISTINCT(session))) AS "Average Duration per Session"
FROM table1
WHERE url ILIKE '%%utm_source%%'
AND ts>='2018-05-01'
AND ts < '2018-06-01'
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 2 DESC)table1
,
(SELECT
CAST((CAST((SUM(bounces)*100) AS FLOAT)/CAST(COUNT(*) AS FLOAT)) AS VARCHAR(5)) + '%' as "Bounce rate"
FROM (
    SELECT
    MIN(ts) AS "time_first_viewed",
    cuuid,
    session,
    COUNT(*) as "number_of_events",
    CASE WHEN count(*) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS bounces
    FROM table1
    WHERE ts>='2018-05-01'
    AND ts < '2018-06-01'
    GROUP BY cuuid, session))table2
```

you defines alias names to your columns and its done.